# Converting C #define constants into variables

Tags: c, constants

I have a device driver where the access to the wifi-router are hard coded using the #define macros in C. where the code looks like:

```
#define SSID                     "XXXX-XXX" 
#define AUTH                      AAAA
#define PSK                       “YYyy00”
```

and the function that use these user defined constants is defined as:

```
router_connect((char *)SSID, sizeof(SSID), AUTH, (char *)PSK, CH_ALL);
```

I'd like to be change these constants as defined .h file as strings that I can read from a SD card and pass it to the function call rather than as hard coded in the main.h file. I'd like to have the ability to change them rather them as stored as fixed ones coded inside a program. After all they are user defined strings, as long as the values are correctly passed between the devices they don't need to be hard coded in the main code.

So I wrote them in the main.c as:

```
extern char SSID[] = "XXXX-XXX";
extern uint8 AUTH  =  AAAA;
extern char PSK[]  = "YYyy00";
```

and in the SD card I have a file setup.txt where I entered the three strings as below in three lines:

```
XXXX-XXX;
AAAA;
YYyy00;
```

I wrote a little routine to read each line from the SD card and assign the strings to the variables
SSID, AUTH, PSK

```
char line[20];  
int line_count;     

FRESULT  my_res;                        
FIL myfil;


my_res = f_open(&myfil, "setup.txt", FA_READ);
if (my_res != FR_OK) {
   printf("file: setup.txt is not found. \n\r");
   /* deal with errors */; 
}

for (line_count = 1; line_count < 4;) {
   f_gets(line, sizeof(line), &myfil); 


   if (line_count == 1) {
      strcpy(SSID, line);
      printf("SSID: %s %s \n\r", SSID, line); 
   }


   if (line_count == 2) {
      strcpy(AUTH, line);
      printf("AUTH: %s %s \n\r", AUTH, line);
   }


   if (line_count == 3) {
      strcpy(PSK, line);
      printf("PSK: %s %s \n\r", PSK, line);
   }

   line_count++;
}
```

My intent was to read these strings from the SD card before the function "router_connect" is called.
I can do that with no problem, when I print out the stings I read from the SD card they are exactly like when they are hard coded, but I find the "router_connect" function does not like the parameters I'm passing.  The device driver works when I hard code the values in the #define statement but for some reason it is not passing the values correctly to the function. Can you please advise if I'm doing it incorrectly for passing parameters to the function call and what will be the right way to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but your setup.txt contains semicolons that you almost certainly don't want in your string.

Comment: Just modify the parameters you pass:
`router_connect(SSID, strlen(SSID), iAuth, PSK, CH_ALL);`

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, it would be nice to see how exactly the function doesn't like those parameters. Secondly, I see that you read the `AUTH` value as a char array, and what the function wants is a `uint8`. How do you pass it? Maybe parsing AUTH into an `uint8` would do the trick.